# Array Holding an another Object

Tags: javascript

```
options: ['Unknown', 'AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE']
```

This is my Options Array and there are 47 states in all. i don't want to add it like this. Instead can i add something like this

```
options: [StateValue] Which would read all the values from the Object.

var StateValue = {
    Unknown: 0,
    AL: 1,
    AK: 2,
    AZ: 3,
    AR: 4,
    CA: 5,
    CO: 6,
    CT: 7,
    DE: 8,
    FL: 9
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through an object like so

```
var StateValue = {
    Unknown: 0,
    AL: 1,
    AK: 2,
    AZ: 3,
    AR: 4,
    CA: 5,
    CO: 6,
    CT: 7,
    DE: 8,
    FL: 9
};

for(var i in StateValue)
    console.log(i + " :: " + StateValue[i]);
```

so you could populate your UI in that way

Comment: If i have to print the states, its actually printing the values.

Comment: @John Cooper I don't follow you

Comment: @John Cooper. That's what the `console.log(i)` does. `i` contains the *keys* while `StateValue[i]` gives you the `values`